# Remote using VPN Client

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a vpn client tools at my laptop at home that can connected to my company servers. The IT Administrator gave it to me.

My habit is usually I didn't turn off my laptop on weekends, this morning I saw my vpn client activated, there's a pop-up said that "VPN Client was terminated by the server....".

But actually I was never activate my vpn client for couple of days. My question, is there possibilities my company network Administrator remoting my laptop without me knowing it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks details.  Do you have a firewall? Do you allow outside sessions to connect to your laptop?  If an vpn session is initiated by you on the laptop, do you have any authentication to do? (Like password, automated secure FOB, etc) A vpn server's configuration usually requires some method of authentication.  Be it with a stored key, password.

A lot of corporations install automatic update software that is installed on their "managed" devices.  This software can initiate a connection (ie phone home) and install updates, applications, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may just have forgotten the vpn on, and when the server rebooted due to an update you got "VPN Client was terminated by the server....".
Anyway, if the laptop is owned by the company they probably might be able to remote control it without the need of your intervention, of course...